Docker GeoServer using jdbcStore isn't persisting new stores or layers when redeployed
I am running GeoServer Docker in a Google Cloud run instance and using a CloudSQL instance for config setting storage with jdbcStore plugin. I was testing some new env vars and deployed a new revision and some recently added layers and stores didn't persist. In the logs I see
Ignoring workspace directory workspaces/EMP
Ignoring workspace directory workspaces/emp
Failed to load data store 'EMP'
I am using the latest geoserver/docker repo with 2.25.3

Does that datastore exist?

It does. The name of the workspace had recently been changed for any added context.

Are you on a windows machine? The message seems to have a case difference which would be important for a Linux container

No. I'm deploying on Google Cloud Run
